# When tryin to do a import, I get error codes which I do not know how to solve

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, authentication

I have two problems the first is that when trying to import AuthService it says "Module '"./auth.service"' has no exported member 'AuthService"

code for the first problem:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
```

code for the second problem:

```
import { PlayerComponent } from ".\component\player\player.component";
import { AddPlayerComponent } from "./components/add-player/add-player.component";
import { GuardService } from "./services/guard.service";
import { LoginComponent } from "./component/login/login.component";
```

The second problem is also with the imports, its says "Cannot find module". Im not really sure if I should write my code on here but this are my problems. How do I solve this?

Comment: It says like you might not have exported the service. check if you have it like `export class AuthService {}`

Comment: Hi Jai thanks for the comment really appreciate it, where should I export the class?

Comment: check the AuthService class if it has export keyword?

Comment: @Jai this is my code for the authservice, where should I export keyword?        
                                                            
import { TestBed } from , '@angular/core/testing';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Comment: You need to check the actual AuthService class.

Comment: As I can see I cannot see that I have a AuthService class. I have the authservice as a typescript, auth.service.spec.ts, Should I do a export keyword in this ts file? @Jai

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an actual AuthService. Try running on the same level of your file `ng generate service auth`; this will generate a service and solve your issue!

Comment: Hi @mikegross I ran my terminal with  ng g service auth earlier, which created auth.spec.ts and auth.service.ts, is the running command you sent the same as the one I did earlier? When tryin to run the code u sent on the terminal I get this error code "A merge conflicted on path "/src/app/auth.service.ts".

Comment: Yes it is the same. By generating your AuthService your are now able to import {AuthService} into your other components

Comment: when I wrote that in the terminal I got the message "A merge conflicted on path "/src/app/auth.service.ts", which means I already generated it? or what I am i doing wrong?

Comment: It will probably be useful to see the content of your module.app.ts and the folder scaffolding to understand what's going on? If your git repo is public please share the link